# How to use (Python AHP) numpy.linalg to derive max eigenvalue (doesn't seem to be converging?)

Tags: python, numpy, eigenvalue, eigenvector

I am a geospatial professional, not a mathematician or programmer. So please do not chastise me for incorrect wording or poor coding. I am simply looking for assistance.

I am using the following code to derive rankings from a pairwise comparison matrix:

```
A = numpy.array(matrix)

"Define vector of weights based on eigenvector and eigenvalues"
eigenvalues, eigenvector=numpy.linalg.eig(A)
maxindex=numpy.argmax(eigenvalues)
eigenvalues=numpy.float32(eigenvalues) #float32
eigenvector=numpy.float32(eigenvector) #float32
weights=eigenvector[:, maxindex]

weights.tolist() #convert array(numpy)  to vector
weights=[ w/sum(weights) for w in weights ]

print "Layer Weights: " + str(numpy.around(weights,3))
```

The problem is, the derived rankings (weights) don't match those from other 3rd party AHP calculators. That is, they appear to be from the first iteration and not the values derived at convergence through multiple iterations.

For example, from the following pairwise reciprocal matrix:

```
[[1.0, 0.333, 0.2, 1.0, 0.333, 0.111],
 [3.0, 1.0, 0.25, 3.0, 1.0, 0.111],
 [5.0, 4.0, 1.0, 3.0, 2.0, 0.111],
 [1.0, 0.333, 0.333, 1.0, 0.333, 0.111],
 [3.0, 1.0, 0.5, 3.0, 1.0, 0.111],
 [9.0, 9.0, 9.0, 9.0, 9.0, 1.0]]
```

I receive the following rankings:

```
[ 0.035  0.074  0.15   0.038  0.08   0.623]
```

When I would expect to receive:

```
[ 0.056  0.074  0.106  0.057  0.076  0.631]
```

Does anybody have any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I cross-checked with Mathematica, which gives the same normalized right eigenvector to the largest eigenvalue as what you got from your Python code. Therefore I suspect that the problem lies with your expectation. Where does it come from? Maybe if you're comparing with some other software it uses some additional tweaks instead of basic AHP.

A coding comment: There is no need for converting to a list for normalizing. You can use `weights = weights/np.sum(weights)` instead.